# Partial Response received from Apigee

Tags: apigee

The flow is SAP NWAS 7/Java AS ---> Apigee On Premise--->Apigee OnCloud -----> Backend. and back.

Backend is posting a response of appx 17 MB back. I have streaming enabled both on cloud and on premise Apigee. But the sap NWAS client states that only partial response is received .

When we invoke from POSTMAN however, we are getting complete response.

Please suggest where the problem can be?

Answer (score 0):

Since Postman works fine for you, it seems like it might be a problem on the client side. So, it's possible that the client requires more info on the response in order to be able to display the content e.g. Content-Type header. Another way to troubleshoot this issue is to send a cURL command to the resource in Apigee and store it in the filesystem to validate that not only Postman can parse the response. e.g.

```
curl http://yourresourcehere/images/12344 > img12344.png
```

Comment: If [this is you](https://community.apigee.com/users/75/dzuluagaapigeecom.html) you should disclose your affiliation in your [user profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1245915/diego) and probably also mention it when you answer questions.